# Prevent selectInput from wrapping text

Tags: r, shiny

In a shiny app, is there a way to prevent the text of the dropdown in `selectInput()` from wrapping, as in the screenshot below? Each option is a long text string. I'd like the dropdown to show each long string on one line, without making a huge sidebar.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121032/difficulty-with-selectize-js-dropdown-overflow-in-mobile) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148411/selectize-dropdown-width-independent-of-input) you can add some custom `css` to the drowpdown

Here's a working example

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        hist(rnorm(input$obs), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 10, max = 500, value = 100),
            selectizeInput(inputId = "si",
                            label =  "select", 
                            choices = c("the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"), 
                            selected = NULL),

            ## Custom css               
            tags$head(
                tags$style(HTML('
                                .selectize-input {
                                    white-space: nowrap;
                                }
                                .selectize-dropdown {
                                    width: 660px !important;
                                }'
                                )
                        )
            )

        ),
        mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))
    )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to customize this for each each drop-down menu?

Comment: most likely yes, but I don't have an example of it at the moment. Might be worth asking a separate question so more people see it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The question is posted here, if you're interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298498/customize-drop-down-width-in-shiny-selectinput

Answer (score 1):

If you do `selectize=False`, within

`selectInput(id="id",label="label",choices=your_choices, selectize=False)`

It will not wrap on your text.