# R Shiny: adjust the width of the dropdown selection area of widget selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

When the item names of the `selectInput` widget is very long, they won't be properly displayed. How can we increase the width of its dropdown selection area while keep the width of the `selectInput` widget unchanged.

Senario:
[image]

Comment: you can use the `width` parameter.

Comment: also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37299152/5977215)

Comment: `width` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I wrap my input filters in a `column()` within a `fluidRow()`. This allows me to use the `width` argument in the `column()` function. The width of the filters should follow the width of the column and expand to fill up.
`fluidRow(
             column(4,
                    wellPanel(
                      div(style="font-size:11px",
                         textInput("EMPLID","Employee ID:")))))`