# Align ActionButton in Shiny App

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

In the app below, I would like to change three aspects of the `ActionButton`:

1. Center the button in its column
2. Reduce the spacing between the button and the top text
3. Increase the spacing between the button and the panels below.

Can this be done within shiny?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             bsCollapse(id="instructionsOutput", open="instructionsPanel",
                        bsCollapsePanel("instructionsPanel",
                                        "This is a panel with text",
                                        style="info"
                                        )
                        )
             ),
      column(12,
             actionButton("p1Button", "Expand/Collapse Text")
             )
    ),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$p1Button, ({
                updateCollapse(session, "instructionsOutput",
                               open="instructionsPanel",
                               close="instructionsPanel")  
  })
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You will need to use CSS and/or javascript in combination with `tags$style` or `tags$script`. Basically, find the `id` or `class` of the item you want to change, then apply appropriate css style to that item. For example, to center a button, apply `align:center`; to reduce spacing on the top, look for `margin-top` or `padding-top` (use `Inspect element` in your browser to find out)

Comment: Another possible solution is to add style code directly to the Shiny elements. For example: `fluidRow(style="padding-bottom:20px;")`. This may not work for some Shiny elements.

Comment: It will work in a similar way to your [other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37151078/5977215) two [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37298498/5977215). As @warmoverflow points out, you need to know the `css` to make these adjustments

Answer (score 6):

Very late reply...but if anyone is looking for a possible solution, you can try the following. Similar to the answer by Xiongbing Jin above, you can add `style` and `align` as arguments to `shiny::column`

```
ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        12,
        bsCollapse(
          id="instructionsOutput", 
          open="instructionsPanel",
          bsCollapsePanel(
            "instructionsPanel",
            "This is a panel with text",
            style="info"
          )
        )
      ),
      column(
        12,
        actionButton(
          "p1Button", 
          "Expand/Collapse Text"
        )
        , align = "center"
        , style = "margin-bottom: 10px;"
        , style = "margin-top: -10px;"
      )
    ),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(),
      mainPanel()
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$p1Button, ({
    updateCollapse(
      session, "instructionsOutput",
      open="instructionsPanel",
      close="instructionsPanel"
    )  
  })
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```